# console log not showing and html isn't changing

Tags: javascript, dom

Okay guys, I have a problem.  For some reason my JavaScript file isn't keeping track on how many times the user choose the "no" class when he selects an option in the select tags.  I'm trying to make it so that when the user selects no in the dropdown list,it keeps track of how many times the user selected no.  Any idea on how to keep track how many times the user selects no without Jquery in javascript?

```
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="quiz" content="myown quiz" />
<title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="machine.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizformatting.css">
<h1>Choose the major right for you</h1>
<pre>
    <form>
    Do you like enjoy programming?
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option class="program">Yes</option>
        <option class="no">No</option>
    </select>

    Do you enjoy 2d animation and 3d animation?
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option class="art">Yes</option>
        <option class="no">no</option>
    </select>

    Do you like music
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option class="no">no</option>
    </select>

    What are your favorite pastimes?
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option class="music">Listening to music</option>
        <option class="program">making websites</option>
        <option class="art">Drawing</option>
        <option class="no">None of these</option>
    </select>

    Out of all the activities you like to do, which one do you enjoy the most?
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option class="art">Painting and drawing</option>
        <option class="music">Playing instruments</option>
        <option class="art">Drawing</option>
        <option class="no">None of these</option>
    </select>

    Would you be interested in making art or coding for video games?
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option class="program">I would be interested in learning the programming languages used to create the scripting for games</option>
        <option class="art">I would like to the models and the environment for modeling</option>
        <option class="no">I'm not interested in either of these options</option>
    </select>

    Do you enjoy making websites or learning how to sing?
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option class="music">Learning how to sing</option>
        <option class="program">making websites for projects</option>
        <option class="no">I'm not interested in any of this</option>
    </select>

    Do you enjoy listening to music more or making programming applications?
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option class="music">I would like to listen to music</option>
        <option class="program">Programming is my thing</option>
        <option class="art">I'm more of a drawer</option>
        <option class="no">I don't like any of these options</option>
    </select>

    Which skillset are you more interested in learning?
    <select>
        <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
        <option class="music">Learning the notes of instruments</option>
        <option class="program">Learning the language of javascript</option>
        <option class="art">I like anime, so I would love to learn how to animate in anime style</option>
        <option class="no">I don't want to do any of these options</option>
    </select>

    Please press the button to get your answer

    <button type="button" onclick="Starting();">Click me</button>
    </form>

</pre>
<p id="yos">Your answer here</p>
```

````
Here is my javascript code:

```javascript
    function Starting() {

    var artchoices = document.querySelectorAll(".art:checked");
    var program = document.querySelectorAll(".program:checked");
    var choice = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");
    var no = document.querySelectorAll(".no:checked");
    var music = document.querySelectorAll(".music:checked");
    var x = document.getElementById("yos");
    var answer = true;

    for (var e = 0; e < choice.length; e++) {
        if (choice[e].selected == true) {
            answer = false;
            break;
        }
    }


    if (answer == false) {
        console.log("Make sure you checked all values");
    } else {
        if (no == 9) {
            console.log("Oh, so you don't want to become anything huh");
            x.innerHTML = "HEY";
        } else {
            if (program > artchoices) {
                console.log("Congrulations, you are an artist");
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = Starting;
}
````

Answer (score -1):

You need to check for the length of the list. The node list (what is returned by `document.querySelectorAll(".no:checked")`) will never equal 9.

```
if (no == 9)
```

needs to be

```
if (no.length === 9)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the answer.